# DRF patch update value in an elegant manner

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to implement a patch API using drf. Inside my ViewSet model, I've something like this:

```
def patch(self, request, id: int, format=None) -> Response:  # type:ignore
        profile: Profile = Profile .objects.get(user__id=id)
        if "username" in request.data:
            profile.username= request.data["username"]
        if "dp" in request.data:
            profile.dp= request.data["dp"]
        if "location" in request.data:
            profile.location.append(request.data["location"])
        profile.save()
```

I'm quite sure that, this is not the appropriate way. Can anyone suggest to me, how I can implement PATCH in, appropriate manner?

If I don't query and send the ID in the request and try to save, it gives me errors regarding relation that, that specific field is not present. Surely it is not, I'm not trying to update it.

And serializer looks something like this:

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = "__all__"
```

Comment: `that specific field is not present` this is a validation that come with the serializer as those field are required, can you add your Serializer code?

Comment: @LinhNguyen that's just with `__all__` fields... and I've added that into the question

Comment: sweet, now add your Profile  model code so we can we which field don't have blank=True

Comment: Most of them, don't have `blank=True,null=Tue`. But as inside patching shouldn't drf take care of it all together?? What if I had 100 fields to be updated optionally? So need a better way to patch..

Comment: `If I don't query and send the ID in the request and try to save` -- Is this using the serializer or just with the model?